# Opções na janela do ❄Winter Bash❄ (escolher, recusar, etc)

Tags: debate

Primeiramente, eu sei o que é "winter bash". A questão aqui é sobre UX.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o que eu vejo no momento. Tem opção na parte de baixo para fazer um "dismiss" (clicanco em "eu odeio chapéus"). Estou postando um print pois não sei se a aparência e recursos mudam conforme o usuário.

A questão é, se não poderia ter um link para uma página explicando o que são os chapéus, de forma mais intuitiva?

Exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clica no link do WINTER BASH na parte do topo, leva ao site sobre os chapéus, o winter bash em geral. Contudo, poderia ser intuitivo com um link mais *user friednly* dentro dessa janelinha. do jeito que está, é difícil perceber que o título na janela é um link.

Senti a falta de uma opção mais intuitiva com link para a página sobre o winter bash. Fica uma impressão de que a única opção é clicar em "eu odeio chapéus".

Parece falho nessa questão do UX. É um detalhe bobo demais, mas eu acho importante pois quando uma interface é realmente boa, o usuário não precisa perguntar como usar.

Abaixo, uma ilustração muito usada entre designers para comparar como uma boa interface não significa ser boa para a experiência do usuário (good ui <> good ux)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entendo que programadores em geral tem uma visão parca sobre design e acham que o usuário tem que se adaptar, no entanto, um bom layout/design deve ser intuitivo o suficiente para que o usuário consiga navegar sem precisar recorrer ao suporte ou ficar confuso ou perdido.

Claro que isso é mera sugestão. Para mim é indiferente se está bom ou ruim. Apenas achei relevante sugerir uma melhoria.

Comment: Há um post no meta a explicar o que é "winter bash": http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5497/129 Clicando no link no inicio dessa janela vai para a página do winter bash (em inglês).

Comment: Tem um link "em destaque" na lateral direita da página: [It's Hat Season…Announcing Winter Bash 2016](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016/?cb=1). E se você clicar no "Winter Bash" ali em cima, vai para [essa página](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) com todos os chapéus (e explicação de como obter).

Comment: Percebi agora que clicando no link do topo leva para a página. Só acho que poderia ser mais user friendly. Não é muito intuitivo.

Comment: Então, @renan, eu nem percebi porque ali é sempre alguma noticia e normalmente em inglês, eu passo batido e nem olho o que aparece ali na lateral. Ainda acho que deveria ter um link ali mesmo dentro da janelinha. Até porque essa lateral só é exibida na home, mas o botão do ❄ winter bash é presente no topo em todas as páginas.

Comment: Concordo com o @DanielOmine , eu também tive dificuldade.

Comment: Se surgiu a pergunta, já é o primeiro indicativo que pode ser mais user-friendly. Se mais de um usuário notou o problema, forte sinal de que REALMENTE pode ser mais user-friendly. E me parece ser o caso aqui.

Comment: Cliquei no "eu odeio chapéus" logo que esse negócio começou. Depois de participar dos que houveram nos anos anteriores, cheguei a conclusão que esse negócio de chapéus é uma pura e total perda de tempo. No entanto, desejo boa sorte e boa diversão para quem curte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu queria poder dar uma resposta melhor do que "eu concordo", mas é tudo que eu posso fazer nesse caso:

- O Winterbash já tá no ar;
- Não dura muito tempo;
- Semana que vem é Natal e Ano Novo e praticamente todo mundo vai estar com suas famílias e entes queridos

O problema, apesar de real como o [Bacco bem descreveu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5556/op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-na-janela-do-winter-bash-escolher-recusar-etc#comment21038_5556), não afeta *tanta* gente, de maneira *tão* grave, numa área *tão* fundamental assim, pra justificar um estudo e melhoria de UX, que provavelmente só ficaria pronto depois do fim do Winterbash, de qualquer maneira.

Fica, basicamente, como sugestão pro futuro.

E se há algum consolo, nós (finalmente?) temos alguém pra ser responsável unicamente pelo UX do Stack Overflow e associados! Alguém cujo trabalho vai ser consertar todas essas coisas construídas por programadores ao longo de 8 anos...

Baita notícia de fim de ano.

Comment: Gabe editei o texto e apeteceu-me escrever "Coitado" depois das reticências :D

Comment: @JorgeB. Será um esforço hercúleo, definitivamente. Foi uma das contratações mais intrigantes desse final de ano. Mal posso esperar pra ver o resultado em 2017