# Criar um tópico no meta para tutoriais referentes ao site

Tags: debate, comunidade

Bom, queria saber a opinião da comunidade a respeito disso, seria assim como funciona o [sandbox](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/sandbox-ou-chiqueirinho-de-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

[Muitos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288667/a-mini-tutorial-for-those-new-to-stack-overflow)(SE) podem falar que o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) já satisfazem essa necessidade, mas **!Nem sempre usuários novos estão dispostos a fazer um tour ou ler a central de ajuda!** mesmo sendo o ideal... Esse é o meu ponto de vista, então um tópico com tutoriais pode vir a ser mais dinâmico, sem contar que quem manteria esse conteúdo seria a própria comunidade.

Entrariam tutoriais de [como identar um código](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52834/diego) usando o `snippets` por exemplo, e outros recursos não muito usuais, mas que podem quebrar um galho.

A ideia seria usar gifs para tornar o aprendizado mais dinâmico, podendo assim serem facilmente linkados em situações que forem necessárias.

---

## Ensinando a identar um código usando o snippet:

[image]

---

## Ensinando a pesquisar por perguntas relacionadas:

[image]
(Com exemplo em real-time :P a pesquisa pelos termos relacionados foi ruim, devia ter testado antes de criar)

Comment: Fica [aqui um exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/182388/revisions) em que uma ajuda dessas seria importante. O AP não estava a perceber a diferença dos [dois possíveis trechos de código](http://i.imgur.com/8vcJLrJ.png)

Comment: Depois de quase uma semana de pergunta feita, acho que seria muito interessante quem negativou explicar o por que acha uma ma ideia :P
Lembrando que aqui é um debate, é uma rede pseudo-democrática onde todos temos voz, e qualquer ponto deve ser exposto sem medo de represália

Comment: Marcelo adorei o pseudo-democrática ahahahah

Answer (score 6):

## Possível solução a caminho

Acredito que isso poderá ser resolvido com um "upgrade" que foi anunciado, em antecipação, pelo @Gabe nesse post:

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5581/4793

> E se há algum consolo, nós (finalmente?) temos alguém pra ser
> responsável unicamente pelo UX do Stack Overflow e associados! Alguém
> cujo trabalho vai ser consertar todas essas coisas construídas por
> programadores ao longo de 8 anos...

## Resumo

Sou a favor de um guia resumido contendo links onde expliquem os recursos básicos de formatação dos textos ou que melhore o manual existente.
Contudo, tenho uma ressalva. Os itens "básicos" desse guia deve ter construído com participação de novatos e "semi-novatos". Pois um experiente demais não vai conseguir enxergar como um novato enxerga. O papel de um experiente seria de orientar, coordenar, nesse caso específico.

O texto abaixo é opinião pessoal, prossiga a leitura se quiser.

## Opinião pessoal

Aparentemente, como é voltado para programadores, nunca houve uma preocupação com UX. Programadores são técnicos e normalmente espera-se que saibam "se virar". Se você "fuçar" nas FAQs e manuais conseguirá encontrar respostas de como navegar.

Progamadores são toscos e anti-sociais. Normalmente respondem algo como:
"bla! leia o manual seu porco preguiçoso".

"Porco preguiçoso" é apenas para descontrair mas muitos pensam assim ou até pior.

No início de carreira eu fui um desses programadores arrogantes. Achava que todos eram burros. Até já fiz uma empresa onde trabalhava, perder um cliente por isso. Aí eu percebi que o burro era eu.

O coitado do usuário entra no caralh# do manual e vê dezenas de milhares de páginas, fica frustrado e desiste. Ninguém quer ler porr@ de manual nenhum. Não estamos aqui para montar um foguete para a NASA. Só queremos saber como navegar e usar os recursos básicos do dia a dia. E essas coisas deveriam ser minimamente intuitivas, de fácil acesso.

Mas independente disso, acredito que mesmo sendo um site técnico, deve ter um mínimo de recursos amigáveis e intuitivos ou ao menos padronizados com o que a maioria já conhece.

Eu lido com IT desde 1998. Portanto acho que entendo um pouco de como navegar em internet, windows, etc. Mas eu percebi que sou preguiçoso ao frequentar esse site do stackoverflow pois constantemente sinto a mesma dificuldade, descrita na pergunta, em conseguir encontrar coisas que poderiam estar mais fáceis.

Eu entrei aqui por volta de 2014 e sentia enorme dificuldade em formatar os textos nesse editor de textos pois é diferente de todos os outros editores de textos com os quais estamos acostumados com as bbcode `[code][/code]`. Aqui o equivalente é um carácter que dependendo do teclado não tem configurado e sou forçado a fazer malabarismos para copiar o carácter de algum lugar.

Aí vem nego me dizer que eu tenho que configurar o teclado. Aí eu penso, "configurar o teclado é o caralh#". Não vou fazer isso só por causa do editor de texto de um sitezinho de perguntinha e respostinha.

Você tem que aprender quase que do ZERO como formatar os textos aqui. É algo que em qualquer fórum por aí, temos o padrão dos bbcode. Mas por favor, não quero entrar no mérito sobre qual é o melhor. Não é essa a discussão. Voltando ao assunto, acho que depois de mais de 1 ano aqui aprendi como que faz para criar um texto grande, para usá-los para blocos de títulos:

## teste1

bla bla bal
bla bla

## teste2

bla bal b

O "segredo" é apenas usar o sharp `#`.

Eu via outros usuários formatando tudo bonitinho com recursos avançados mas eu não conseguia.

Eu sei que tem o manual no link de ajuda

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo assim "não ajuda em nada" pois sequer menciona esse recurso do sharp: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Mas o problema ali é, além de não ser "completo", possui falhas de design (UX).

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe os links "ver mais". Apesar de estar na cor vermelha, são minúsculos e nunca tinha clicado neles. Se tivesse clicado há 3 anos atrás, teria descoberto como usar o sharp. Mas justamente por não ser de fácil acesso, nunca tinha clicado nesses links. Pois são tão pequenos que passam desapercebidos e dão também, uma sensação de que você terá que gastar mais tempo para conseguir aprender o que quer.

Eu aprendi a usar o sharp depois que atingi um certo nível de pontuação onde foi me permitido editar postagens alheias. Então aprendi diversos recursos de formatação apenas fuçando no editor em postagens de usuários mais experientes.

Percebe como isso é ridículo? É um esforço enorme para usar recursos básicos.

Hoje, eu já me acostumei a usar o site pois estou fazendo 3 anos aqui em 2017, mas ainda tem recursos onde preciso buscar no google e encontro em blogs terceiros como usar ou muitas vezes em perguntas no [metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Ou seja, tem que dar a volta ao mundo para descobrir algo que poderia estar aqui debaixo do seu nariz. Veja também que eu até evito perguntar aqui no meta pois normalmente dá desânimo perguntar esse tipo de coisa devido aos que negativam "indiscriminadamente". Mas se um usuário mais famoso, com muitas pontuações postar, recebe positivos. Mas enfim, isso é algo polêmico e deve ser tratado em outra ocasião.

Quando um site tem uma boa UX, o usuário não precisa perguntar como navegar e usar recursos do dia a dia. Mas aqui acontece muito disso, dos usuários terem dificuldade em usar coisas simples.

Para quem vive aqui dentro "24 horas", pode parecer que tudo isso é bobagem e frescura de preguiçoso, mas eu afirmo que não é. É preciso entender como que o usuário novato enxerga o ambiente e, quem é mais antigo e vive aqui dentro, respira isso aqui 24h, não consegue enxergar e acha que o universo tem que se adaptar com o ambiente do SO-pt.

Mesmo alguém um pouco mais experiente sente certas dificuldades mas como já criou hábitos e técnicas de malabarismo, consegue se virar inventando gambiarras. Mas não quer dizer que isso resolve. Pois o problema continua e se não melhorar, sempre existirá novatos fazendo essas perguntas sobre como usar recursos básicos do site **que poderiam ser intuitivos e de fácil acesso**, conforme descrevi nos textos acima.

Outra coisa que é mais frustrante ainda é quando alguém faz perguntas desse tipo aqui no meta, é quase certeza que receberá negativos.

Inclusive, eu estendi essa resposta incluindo esses casos que experimentei justamente devido aos negativos que a sua pergunta recebeu.

Eu acho esses negativos sem razão (para casos específicos como esse) e isso é algo relevante pois desestimula a participação. Mas isso é outro assunto, não cabe misturar aqui. Mas no geral, um usuário experiente não liga mais para pontuação. Mas um novato vê um negativo as vezes como ofensa, repúdio, etc. Algo como "Hey, vc não deve perguntar isso, saia daqui, cai fora".
Não sei se os funcionários do SO e os mais velhos no ambiente conseguem entender isso.

Para se ter uma noção, recentemente postei uma questão aqui no meta referente ao UX. Inicialmente logo quando postei, recebeu negativos. Tinha mais do que 2 negativos e poucos positivos. Na verdade balanceado. Eu me senti como se estivesse perdendo tempo em postar aqui. Tirei um tempo do meu dia para prover um feedback de melhorias e recebo pedradas. É assim que a gente se sente. Não sei de onde raios que vem esses negativos que sequer explicam o que pode estar errado. Mas enfim, ao invés de levar para o lado pessoal ou ficar de mimimi, pensei que aquilo poderia ser uma oportunidade e foi o que fiz.

A pergunta original estava bem clara e bem formatada. Aí me perguntei "será que essa turma que negativa é burra demais para entender? Preciso desenhar?"

E foi isso mesmo. Eu DESENHEI para explicar e tive que criar argumentações sobre o UX. E logo após colocar a imagem do parque, https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHJUh.jpg, recebi uma chuva de positivos e alguns negativos foram removidos.

Aqui tem umas pessoas que são muito lentas para entender as coisas. Tem que escrever um texto gigante explicando cada detalhe, desenhar, colocar imagem ilustrativa, etc, como se estivesse conversando com uma criança de 3 anos de idade quando é um assunto que foge da área de programação ou da área técnica.

Felizmente parece que isso vem mudando ultimamente. Estamos tendo uma participação mais ativa de usuários com um nível intelectual maior. Aquela velha cultura do "leia o manual seu porco preguiçoso", está enfraquecendo.

Se mais usuários não se abalarem com negativos, e procurarem oportunidades em problemas, maiores serão as chances de melhorias pois estaremos em maior número em relação aos verdadeiros "porcos preguiçosos".

Comment: Ótima resposta na minha opinião, tenho essa mesma impressão, vale salientar que o pessoal de exatas costuma adorar imagens, gráficos ilustrativos que as vezes melhoram a percepção do todo, na maioria dos casos isso é uma ótima coisa, mas não em todas.

Comment: Daniel Omine foi exatamente o que aconteceu comigo só aprendi a fazer títulos usando # e o <kbd> também ao editar outras publicações ;)

Comment: Ia dar um -1 só para ser do contra mas não fui capaz :P Reagiste muito bem aos -1, é assim mesmo, há que ver a oportunidade em vez de ficar a choramingar ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Ensinando a criar links

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Criar e remover comentários

[image]